# How can I send state to another component in react?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I would like to ask how can I send state from component to another component?
I have 3 components and I want to send data between them. So I have an input component where I handle an IP call and I want to send this shortedLink state to another component, so I can render that data. I don't know that is it clear what I want to do, but I hope so :D

```js
import ShortedLinks from './ShortedLinks'

const testimonials = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ShortedLinks />
        </div>
    );
};

export default testimonials;
```

```js
const shortedLinks = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>I want to get the state here</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default shortedLinks;
```

```js
const InputSection = () => {
  const [shortedLink, setShortedLink] = useState("")
    
  return (...);
};

export default InputSection;
```

Comment: You need to provide some description of your component tree for anyone to give you a decent answer to this.

Comment: Oke, sorry. So I have 3 components: Testimonials is the parent of the ShortedLinks component. And the InputSection is just a separated component and I want to send the shortedLink state to the Testimonials whithout returning it from the InputSection. I hope it makes sense :D

Comment: Are you able to lift the component state up to the lowest common parent?

Comment: I don't think so, or I don't know, sorry I am lost a little bit..

Comment: If you add a picture of your exact component tree (file structure), an actual answer can be given without guesswork. Otherwise, I would recommend learning about state lifting. If you then discover this isn't practical for your specific issue, then you may possibly require something like the `useContext()` hook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the props to achieve it like this :

```
import ShortedLinks from './ShortedLinks'

const Testimonials = () => {
  const [shortedLink, setShortedLink] = useState("")
  return (
      <div>
          <ShortedLinks shortedLink={shortedLink} />   // Pass props here
      </div>
  );
};

export default Testimonials;
```

And then in your `ShortedLinks` component

```
const ShortedLinks = ({shortedLink}) => {    // Get props here
   return (
       <div>
           <h1>{shortedLink}</h1>
       </div>
   );
};

export default ShortedLinks;
```

And if you can't use the props like this you can use the `useContext` like this :

```
import React,{ useState, createContext } from "react";

export const ShortedLinkContext = createContext('');

const InputSection = () => {

  const [shortedLink, setShortedLink] = useState("")
    
  return (
      <ShortedLinkContext.Provider value={shortedLink}>
          ....
      </ShortedLinkContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default InputSection;
```

And finally you can comsume the context here :

```
import {ShortedLinkContext} from ....

const ShortedLinks = () => {
 const shortedLink = useContext(ShortedLinkContext);
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>{shortedLink}</h1>
      </div>
    );
};

export default shortedLinks;
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you man, but it's not what I want because my state is in the InputSection component and I'm not returning any components from this InputSection.

Comment: @Surge I have updated the response with the useContext solution

Comment: Thank you much for your effort, now it says that 'shortedLink' was used before it was defined, I did everyhing like you said

Comment: @Surge it was a typo in ShortedLinks, you can retry, and see https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp